# Retrieve winner of arraylist JAVA

Tags: java

Well, i'm creating a small game where I've to retrieve a winner from an arraylist.

```
private static ArrayList<Person> setWinner(ArrayList<Person> pers)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < pers.size(); i++)
    {
        if(pers.get(i).getPoints() //Stuck here...
    }
    return pers; 
}
```

How can I check which players has the most points?

Comment: Create a variable that holds the max score and check each players points against that. If they have more than the current max, then update the max and keep on going. At the end you will have the max score

Comment: @GBlodgett Do you have any examples how? I'm not 100 percent sure how you mean - and what if none has maxscore?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
private static ArrayList<Player> getWinners(ArrayList<Player> players)
{
    ArrayList<Player> l = new ArrayList<Player>();
    int maxPoints = -1; //Assuming it is not possible to have negative points

    for (int i = 0; i < players.size(); i++)
    {
        int points = players.get(i).getPoints();
        if (points >= maxPoints) {
            if (points > maxPoints) {
                l.clear(); //Clear the return list, since a new "best score" was found
            }
            maxPoints = points;
            l.add(players.get(i));
        }
    }
    return l; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```
if (players == null || players.size() == 0) {
 throw new RuntimeException("You had no players!!");
}


Player winner = players.get(0);

for (Player p: players) {
 if (p.getScore() > winner.getScore) {
  winner = p;
 }
}

winner; // here you got player with the most score.
```

Comment: Do I have to add a for-loop for the Player winner = players.get(0) ? since I need to get all players? so I should add like players.get(i);?

Comment: @SwiftPrezy That line he is just setting the first `Player` as the initial highest scoring player to compare to the next ones.  He uses the enhanced `for` loop to loop through the rest to find the higher player.  Though this approach needs to be modified if multiple highest scoring players have the same score.

Comment: im getting error : java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0

Comment: Hard to tell why since there is explicit check for empty arrays at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

What about a solution using `Streams`:

```
private static List<Player> getWinners(List<Player> players) {
    // Use TreeMap  with reverse order comparator; the highest point will be the first
    Supplier<Map<Integer, List<Player>>> mapFactory = () -> new TreeMap<>(Comparator.reverseOrder());
    Map<Integer, List<Player>> map = Optional.of(players).orElse(Collections.emptyList()).stream()
                                             .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Player::getPoints, mapFactory, Collectors.toList()));
    // map.keySet() is sorted desc order all points
    return map.isEmpty() ? Collections.emptyList() : map.get(map.keySet().iterator().next());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you got some sort of multiple winners for some reasons, I assume that winner is player that more points that some treashold, and probably only fixed numer of such players (eg 1st 2nd 3rd place).

```
    int winningScoreTreashold=5///somethis;
            int winningPlayersCount=3;
            List<Player> winners = players.stream()
                    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Player::getScore))
                    .filter(p -> p.getScore() > winningScoreTreashold)
                    .limit(winningPlayersCount)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

   winners//here you got winners;
```

remove any conditions that does not fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could work:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Player> players = new ArrayList<>();
        players.add(new Player("Adam", 1));
        players.add(new Player("Bob"));
        players.add(new Player("Cameron", 2));
        players.add(new Player("Daniel", 2));
        System.out.printf("Players: %s%n", players);
        players.sort(Comparator.comparing(Player::getPoints));
        System.out.printf("Sorted Players: %s%n", players);
        List<Player> winners = getWinners(players);
        System.out.printf("Winners: %s%n", winners);
    }

    public static List<Player> getWinners(List<Player> players) {
        int maxPoints = Collections.max(players, Comparator.comparing(Player::getPoints)).getPoints();
        return players.stream().filter(p -> p.getPoints() == maxPoints).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Assuming your `Player` class looks something like this:

```
class Player {
    private String name;
    private int points;

    Player(String name, int points) {
        this.name = name;
        this.points = points;
    }

    Player(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.points = 0;
    }

    public void updatePoints(int newPoints) {
        this.points = newPoints;
        return;
    }

    public int getPoints() {
        return this.points;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s: %d", this.name, this.points);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Players: [Adam: 1, Bob: 0, Cameron: 2, Daniel: 2]
Sorted Players: [Bob: 0, Adam: 1, Cameron: 2, Daniel: 2]
Winners: [Cameron: 2, Daniel: 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to sort the players' array first.
2. return everything that matches the score of the first item.

```
private static ArrayList<Player> getWinners(ArrayList<Player> players) {
        if (players.isEmpty()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("players list is empty");
        }

        // sort the array (desending)
        Comparator<Player> comparator = (Player t, Player t1) -> t1.getPoints() - t.getPoints();
        Collections.sort(players, comparator);

        // filter the array
        Predicate<Player> prdct = (Player t) -> t.score == players.get(0).getPoints();
        List<Player> winners = players.stream().filter(prdct).collect(Collectors.toList());

        return new ArrayList<>(winners);
    }
```

Hope this helps!